How to create a conversation in gohighlevel via API?
I have found APIs to create, update and get conversations on gohighlevel. In documentation they mentioned "Creates a new conversation with the data provided" for POST request.
To make a POST call to
https://services.leadconnectorhq.com/conversations/

with body
body: {
  "locationId": "tDtDnQdgm2LXpyiqYvZ6",
  "contactId": "tDtDnQdgm2LXpyiqYvZ6"
}

And there will be response like:
{
  "success": true,
  "conversation": {
    "id": "tDtDnQdgm2LXpyiqYvZ6",
    "locationId": "tDtDnQdgm2LXpyiqYvZ6",
    "contactId": "tDtDnQdgm2LXpyiqYvZ6",
    "assignedTo": "tDtDnQdgm2LXpyiqYvZ6",
    "userId": "tDtDnQdgm2LXpyiqYvZ6",
    "lastMessageBody": "Hello, this is the message body",
    "lastMessageDate": "1628008053263",
    "lastMessageType": "TYPE_CALL",
    "unreadCount": 1,
    "inbox": true,
    "starred": true,
    "deleted": false
  }
}

I want to create a conversation for a PhoneCall. How can I pass data in body of the request? there is no details in the documentation so if someone helps in it? please

You mean how to find "locationId" and "contactId" ?

I have found the location ID, but where to get the contactID and also how to pass other data to create a conversation type Phone Call?
Like Create NOTES. we can pass data (parameters/variables) including Duration of Call, Queue Name and others call related data.

You can upsert a contact before creating a conversation.

You can use the GET CONTACTS API to retrieve a list of all contacts, which includes the contactID for each contact. Additionally, from the GHL, you can export all or selected contacts from contacts tab and then find the contact ID for a particular contact.
To create a new conversation of type phone, you should pass the lastMessageType as TYPE_CALL. There are other types available as well. It is better to refer to the documentation https://highlevel.stoplight.io/docs/integrations/8d0b19e09176e-create-conversation to find the best option for you.

Thanks for the answer. but in documentation they have not mentioned what to pass in the request body. only the two parameters contactID and LocationId is being passed.
what the request body look like? as we have to add QueueName, AgentName, Duration, Direction and Recording link with the request so it can create a conversation activity.
